# Having trouble implementing promises with setTimeout and running them in parallel

Tags: javascript, promise

I am trying to write a function that would returns an asynchronous promise. Using a `setTimeout` of 100ms to simulate promise resolve, except for G(one of the promises) it's `setTimeout` is 200ms. Each step is separate asynchronous promise.

I want each promise to start after the previous step has completed.
    All promises log their names & income parameters to console and provide name as a result to next promises.
    Basic flow :
    a -> (b + c + d) -> e -> f -> h -> i -> j
                         `->   g  ->  /

Here:
    (b+c+d) - means that 3 promises should be running in parallel
    'i' waits for both g & h.
    Results from each previous task should be provided to next task.

```
var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject)) {
    setTimeout(resolve, 100);
});

Promise.all([promise.resolve(a), promise.resolve(b+c+d), promise.resolve(e), promise.resolve(f), promise.resolve(g)...]).then(function(values) {
    console.log(values);
});
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include your code so we have an idea of what you're starting with, and the desired output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want one promise to `resolve` after other, chain them using `.then()`. If you want some promises to `resolve` in parallel, use `Promise.all()`

```
/**
 * promiseGenerator: will generate a new promise which will resolve after <time> ms
 * time: time in milliseconds
 * */
function promiseGenerator(time){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
        setTimeout(()=>resolve("resolved after " + time),time)
    });
}

time=100;
a = promiseGenerator(time);

    a.then((value) => {
        console.log('a resolved');
        b = promiseGenerator(time);
        c = promiseGenerator(time);
        d = promiseGenerator(time);
        return Promise.all([b, c, d])//this promise will be resolved after each of b,d,d are resolved, in any order
    })
    .then((value) => {
        console.log('b,c,d resolved');
        e = promiseGenerator(time);
        return e
    })
    .then((value) => {
        console.log('e resolved');
        f = promiseGenerator(time);
        return f
    })
    .then((value) => {
        console.log('f resolved');
        g = promiseGenerator(time*2);
        return g
    })
    .then((value) => {
        console.log('g resolved');
    });
```